# Update query throwing temp space issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle

below query when run with large data throws temp space error (not able to increase temp space). I think the issue is with the way query is written. Could someone please help in rewriting the query more efficiently:

```
UPDATE  TABLE1 tab 
SET tab.tgt_col = 1
WHERE tab.id1 IN (
      SELECT 
      Id1 FROM  TABLE1 t1 WHERE
      t1.id1 NOT IN ( SELECT Min(id1) FROM  TABLE1 t2
                      WHERE t2.date_col= :A
                      AND t1.col1 = t2.col2
                      AND t1.col2 =t2.col2
                      AND t1.col3 =t2.col3
                      AND t1.col4 =t2.col4
                      AND Nvl(t1.col5, 'XX') =Nvl(t2.col5, 'XX')
                      AND t1.col6 = t2.col6
                       AND t1.col7 = t2.col7
                       AND To_Char(t1.col_time,'YYYYMMDD') = To_Char(t2.col_time,'YYYYMMDD')
                      )
      AND t1.col7  IN('a','b','c')
      AND t1.date_col = :A
      AND t1.COUNTRY IN ('US','CA')
      AND t1.col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table2 F
                                    WHERE F.col8 IN (SELECT col8 FROM table3
                                                                    WHERE date_col=:A AND col9 = 1 )
                                                                                AND F.col10 = '1')
      )
AND  tab.date_col = :A;
```

Comment: Can you execute the SELECT part without problem? If so try to split the UPDATE in, for example, 3 parts - `t1.col7 = 'a'`, `t1.col7 = 'b'` and `t1.col7 = 'c'`. Also try to rewrite the last IN clause as INNER JOIN. The `IN` is not space friendly

Comment: thanks Evgeni. could you please help with rewriting the last IN clause as INNER JOIN.

Comment: Something like this `SELECT col1 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.col8 = table3.col8 AND table3.date_col = :A AND table3.col9 = 1 AND table2.col10 = '1'` but try it first in SQL Plus or Toad

Comment: thanks. I think Merge can improve.please advise